# How do I make a good northeast arrow to represent continued fractions?

Tags: arrows, fractions

I'm taking notes on a book which represents continued fractions like this:

[image: Representation of continued fractions with northeast pointing arrows]

When I'm doing this in LaTeX, I've been using \nearrow, but that looks more like this:
[image: Attempt using \nearrow]

I don't love how everything is on the same level and how far apart the numbers are. Is there a way I can make it look more like how it is in the book? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. // It would be very helpful, if you could add code which: a) is minimal, b) compiles when we copy it, c) shows your problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yet another continued fraction notation!

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\DeclareInstance{xfrac}{cmr}{text}{
  slash-symbol=$\nearrow$,
  slash-right-kern=-0.33333em,
  slash-left-kern=-0.33333em,
  numerator-top-sep=-0.5ex,
  denominator-bot-sep=-1ex,
  h-scale=1.5,
  v-scale=1.5,
}

\newcommand{\Cfrac}[2]{\textup{\sfrac{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\Cfrac{1}{3}+\Cfrac{1}{2}+\Cfrac{1}{4}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]